# Incorrect result of difference two double numbers

Tags: c#

Why I get incorrect result.(for example n=3.83 I expect temp=0.83 but when trace my code temp=0.83000000000000007)
notice:temp,m and n are double.

```
n = double.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        m = Math.Floor(n);
        Console.WriteLine(m);
        temp = n - m;
```

Answer (score -1):

The reason is precision of `double`. The store numbers only approximately. Therefore, you can have difference in lower digits. Usually it's not critical, but bad when:

- You want an exact answer.
- The error accumulates.